# Difference between \p{Alpha} and \p{L} in Java

Tags: java, regex

As I get it `\p{L}` include all letters from Unicode symbols, `\p{Alpha}` is slightly the same but only for Latin letters(ASCII). At my work I have 'A' latin and 'A' cyrillic, and `\p{Alpha}` in old java  code don't match cyrillic symbols as letters. As I test it the `\p{L}` is solution for me. Can you folks give me some advice for this situation and what i shoud use in java code? On this page http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html use `\p{Alpha}` for java code.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `\p{Alpha}` is a POSIX character class implementation that will match extended characters only when used in combination with [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) (or `(?U)` flag), while `\p{L}` will always match all Unicode letters from the BMP plane. Note you can write `\p{L}` as `\pL` or `\p{IsL}`.

See more [reference details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> Both `\p{L}` and `\p{IsL}` denote the ***category of Unicode letters***.
>   
>   **POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)**
>   `\p{Lower}` A lower-case alphabetic character: `[a-z]`
>   `\p{Upper}` An upper-case alphabetic character:`[A-Z]`
>   `\p{Alpha}` An alphabetic character:`[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`

Have a look at the [following demo](http://ideone.com/xwKCDR):

```
String l = "Abc";
String c = "Абв";
System.out.println(l.matches("\\p{Alpha}+"));     // => true
System.out.println(c.matches("\\p{Alpha}+"));     // => false
System.out.println(c.matches("(?U)\\p{Alpha}+")); // => true
System.out.println(l.matches("\\p{L}+"));         // => true
System.out.println(c.matches("\\p{L}+"));         // => true
```